# Xcode 8.3 and choice for xib or storyboard

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

Creating a new project in the Xcode 8.3 version does not offer anymore the choice between the previous previous XIB and the current Storyboard option for the interface file. Is this not available anymore or is there an option to reactivate this option?. I can't find any information about this subject and did nor read anything about Apple removing this option.

Comment: Just a work-round. I found an older version (8.2) of Xcode in my Applications folder and used it to create the project, then switched back to the current version to carry on working.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. I already knew that because I opened a project from 8.2.1 in 8.3 and it did work. The important issue is that the problem is only postponed for as long as Apple supports it and I am afraid this will also be discarded in future releases of Xcode. I am now trying to learn using Storyboards which is not very easy. But that's the way it is. A very good tutorial and examples from Apple could help us develop faster and beter!!

Answer (score 1):

The option was removed on purpose - according to Apple. The route is now to use Storyboards.

Alas - I cannot provide a link to that information. I filed a bug-report with Apple after noticing that that option was no longer visible. The bug-report was closed with the following remark

---

Please know that our engineering team has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the information provided.  It always uses storyboards now. This is an intentional change.

---

Comment: This actually does seem to provide an answer to the question, but could be improved with a reference.